Does anyone here used uniswap sepolia?
I want to swap with usdc but dont know how. It says tokens loaded by local storage. How I'm gonna add to it?
BEWARE: The Uniswap interface uses localStorage to remember your settings, such as which tokens you have imported.
You should always use an IPFS gateway that enforces origin separation, or our hosted deployment of the latest release at
-> https://github.com/Uniswap/interface/releases?page=3
